# Time Overlapping sum

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, view, procedure

I have a table structured like this:

```
id_task INTEGER,
task_begin DATETIME,
task_end DATETIME
```

I have rows like this:

```
id_task     task_begin              task_end
1           2015-03-23 09:00:00     2015-03-23 09:14:00
2           2015-03-23 09:10:00     2015-03-23 09:16:00
3           2015-03-23 09:18:00     2015-03-23 09:24:00
4           2015-03-23 09:21:00     2015-03-23 09:23:00
5           2015-03-23 09:24:00     2015-03-23 09:26:00
6           2015-03-23 09:26:00     2015-03-23 09:45:00
7           2015-03-23 09:30:00     2015-03-23 09:36:00
8           2015-03-23 09:34:00     2015-03-23 09:39:00
9           2015-03-23 09:05:00     null
10          null                    null
11          2015-03-23 10:02:00     2015-03-23 10:14:00
12          2015-03-23 10:04:00     2015-03-23 10:10:00
13          2015-03-23 10:03:00     2015-03-23 10:13:00
14          2015-03-23 10:10:00     null
15          2015-03-23 10:20:00     2015-03-23 10:30:00
16          2015-03-23 10:40:00     2015-03-23 10:50:00
```

I want to select the actual working times without overlap. The result will be like this:

```
task_begin              task_end
2015-03-23 09:00:00     2015-03-23 09:16:00
2015-03-23 09:18:00     2015-03-23 09:45:00 
2015-03-23 10:02:00     2015-03-23 10:14:00
2015-03-23 10:20:00     2015-03-23 10:30:00
2015-03-23 10:40:00     2015-03-23 10:50:00
```

How can I do it with SELECT or with Procedure in MySQL?

Comment: It will be easier in a procedural language than in SQL.

Comment: @RickJames maybe you right, I change the question, I'am open for any solutions.

Comment: I was already including Stored Procedures when trying to chase you away from SQL.  Maybe @fancyPants has a good solution.

Comment: @RickJames I wanted solve in MySQL because it can calculate faster than any server side code and this example will be expanded with my real problem. This problem will be use in views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(task_begin) AS task_begin, MAX(task_end) AS task_end
FROM (

    SELECT
    t.*,
    @rc := IF(@prev_task_end >= task_begin, @rc, @rc + 1) AS rc,
    @prev_task_end := task_end
    FROM
    t,
    (SELECT @rc := 0, @prev_task_end := null) var_init_subquery
    ORDER BY id_task

) sq
GROUP BY rc
HAVING task_begin IS NOT NULL OR task_end IS NOT NULL
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1684a/4/0)
- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) you can read more about using variables in queries

Comment: Working nice and fast! I can use the session variables in view with setter and getter functions :)